# Create the UISearchBar behavior with an UIView in a tableHeaderView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, header, uisearchbar

If i had an UISearchBar to the tableHeaderView the search bar automatically hides when i scroll down the table view. I want the same behavior but instead add an UISearchBar to the tableHeaderView i want to add an UIView.

This is an video of the problem:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NPTRaT2A5vU

Answer (score 1):

Use a TableView in a ViewController (not a TableViewController) and then add just the SearchBar to the top of that view (resize the tableview down to accomodate).  I do this with almost all of my VC's where I need to filter using the SearchBar.  This keeps the searchbar visible all the time and works well.

I can send a complete example if I need to

Comment: This is not the solution that i want. Instead of an UIsearchBar i want  and UIView that have the same behavior of the UISearchBar wich is when  i scroll up the view appears but when a scroll down the view hides behind the navigationbar.

Answer (score 1):

I have yet to see a solution that *properly* mimics the automatic (undocumented, as far as I can see) scroll behaviour you get from a UISearchBar assigned to a UITableView.tableHeaderView within a UINavigationController. Besides your video, this behaviour can also be seen in Apple's iOS apps like Mail and Music.

One way I found to achieve this is to assign a UISearchBar to the tableHeaderView then add your custom view over the top of the UISearchBar (which is a UIView subclass). You still get the special table scrolling behaviour to hide & reveal the table header, but with your own view instead. This assumes you can make your view the same size as a UISearchBar.

For example, in viewDidLoad:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [[[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 44.0f)] autorelease];
[self.tableView.tableHeaderView addSubview:myView];
```

Admittedly, a bit of a hack, but this strategy does appear to work.

Answer (score 0):

So literally what that video does is it does not add a tableHeaderView and it puts the custom view in the first cell using the cells .contentView property and then it starts to add the test cells. So the cellViewForIndexPath method you take the indexPath and check to see if it is 0 if so then add your custom view. Else then add the cells. All the video does is moves the cells down by one and adds to cell0 a view by using the code

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:CustomView];
```

That is all you need to put a custom view on there.

Comment: No. I want that the red rectangle in the video that is in the table header view has the same behavior of the search bar. In the video the search bar hides when i scroll down but the uiview (red rectangle) doesn't hide. I want to hide the red rectangle when i scroll down just like the search bar.

Comment: The red rectangle is inside the table header view and not in the table view cells.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone reads this, like me, I have found a solution for this issue. It's pretty simple

```
myTableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, heightOfView);
```

So you have to know the height of the view for this and there is one other downside to this solution. If there is not enough content in the table view to be scrollable and you scroll down the view will be revealed and you can't hide it anymore. In my case this is acceptable for now.

If there is anyone who got the UISearchBar functionality working with a UIView. Please post :)

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

To reiterate Daan Vermeulen's answer, simply offsetting scroll view by the height of searchbar will do the trick. Since I am adding the searchbar in the table's header view, I am moving the scroll up by the height of header view's height. I am targeting iOS8 and this goes to viewdidload method; so the code bit is as follows:

```
//initiate the search controller
//use the original tableview controller itself to manage search
//don't dim the underlying content to show the filtered results as the user types into the search bar.
//search scope bar is not used. assign an empty array to the scopebuttontitles property (this is required with iOS8)
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = [[NSArray alloc] init];

//use the original tableview controller as a delegate and implement the UISearchResultsUpdating protocol
//add the search bar view to the table view header
//search view covers the table view when active. make the table view controller define the presentation context
//to ensure that search bar fits the screen. (this is required with iOS8)
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
[self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];

//offset scrollview content by tableheaderview height
self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.tableView.tableHeaderView.bounds.size.height);
```